# Seeking Original Aramaic for Talmudic Phrase

Tags: sources-mekorot, aramaic, talmud-yerushalmi

What is the original Aramaic of this phrase:

> May the words of the Torah be burned rather than handed over to women.

I think it is in Sotah in the Jerusalem Talmud.

Comment: How do you know the Talmud says this? Where did you see it?

Answer (score 8):

[תלמוד ירושלמי מסכת סוטה דף טז עמוד א; פרק ג הלכה ד](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3703.htm)

אמר ליה ישרפו דברי תורה ואל ימסרו לנשים.‏

*מטרונה שאלה את רבי לעזר מפני מה חט אחת במעשה העגל והן מתים בה שלש מיתות.  אמר לה אין חכמתה של אשה אלא בפילכה דכתיב (שמות לה) וכל אשה חכמת לב בידיה טוו.  אמר לו הורקנוס בנו בשביל שלא להשיבה דבר אחד מן התורה איבדת ממני שלש מאות כור מעשר בכל שנה.  אמר ליה ישרפו דברי תורה ואל ימסרו לנשים.*‏

Comment: It should be noted, though, that Meiri states that he meant this statement hyperbolically (דרך גוזמא).